# Missing thumbnail when posting SWF on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, flash

I'm want to post SWF on facebook, everything works fine, except one thing, thumbnail are missing. This is the code used:

```
$fb->api('/USER_ID/feed', 'POST', array(
                                    'message' =>'title',
                                    'link' => 'link',
                                    'name' => 'name',
                                    'description' => 'description',
                                    'source' => 'swf file url',
                                    'picture' => 'picture url'
                                ));
```

All values are properly completed, image is not missing from my server (I checked many times), again, everything works fine, but thumbnail is missing. I have also OG meta tags on my page, if I post link directly, everything is perfect, thumbnail appears, but if I use PHP, thumbnail is missing. Where can be the problem?